# Best way to create a trenchcoat for a game character

Tags: sculpting, cloth-simulation

I m fairly new to blender.  I wanted to create a noir-style game character with a trench coat.
Can u tell me what would be the best way to create the trench coat for the character? Do I sculpt it on the character while sculpting or character or do I create its topology after I have sculpted the character? Also, I want to add cloth simulation to the lower part of the trenchcoat. What would be the best way to do this if I want to do retopology and bake normals after I have done sculpting. Thnx

Comment: in my opinion it's much safer to sculpt 2 objects: your character + its coat, for practical reasons + if you ever need your character without french coat. Later, if you think it's better to merge the 2, you'll be able to do it.

Comment: I don't intend to use the character without the trenchcoat. So do I create them separately and then merge them and then do the retopology. PLz correct me if i m wrong

Comment: It would be risky to advice you  ;)  so maybe try only one object and see if it creates some issues, anyway you'll be able to go back, I would be interested to hear how you manage and if it works fine